# Wild Oscillations Of Functions

Tags: calculus

Can we define a function to be wildly oscillating near a point $c$ as for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $k$ such that $f(x)-k$ changes it's sign at infinitely many points in the interval $(c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$??If No then how to define a function to be wildly oscillating near a point $c$??

Comment: We can make any definition we want, so it's hard to understand what you're asking in this question. By what criterion are you evaluating whether a particular definition of "wildly oscillating" is good or not?

Comment: Can we define in the manner I did?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$ has that property for $c=k=0$.It is even continuous in 0.

Comment: But it also wildly oscillates near $0$

Comment: Yes, it oscillates at `c=0`.

Comment: So can we defined wild Oscillation as I did?

Comment: What's unclear about my example? Your question was how to define a function that oscillates in each environment of some point, no?

Comment: No my question was not to define a function but to define when a function is said to be wildly oscillating near a point.